# JWT Auth wrong user provided from token

Tags: angularjs, laravel, jwt

I created 2 accounts with different email addresses and passwords. I have a HTTP request that sends the token (stored in local storage after signin) like this:

```
http://apiurl/api/projects/getProjects?token=tokenString
```

Inside the method, I used the following line to retrieve the authenticated user based on the token:

```
$authenticatedUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

This retrieves the email address for the first account I created, even if I sign in on the second account. For each account the token in the request is different but the authenticatedUser is for the same account every time.

This only ever happens for one specific account, where it thinks I am logged in as a different user. If I remove all my users from the database and create some new accounts, then one of them will have this same issue.

Comment: what is the identifier column of your user table like? is it 'id'?

Comment: Yes, 'id' is the primary key of the users table, if that's what you are asking?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

One note. I think you shouldn't send the token in the url query parameter for security reasons. Refer [here](https://www.fullcontact.com/blog/never-put-secrets-urls-query-parameters/).

I recommend sending it inside cookie. In express.js, like this.

```
res.cookie("auth", token);
return res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/socialauthredirect`);
```